# Does ${\rm rk} AB \le {\rm min} ({\rm rk} A, {\rm rk} B)$ hold over a sum?

Tags: matrix-rank

For matrices $A, B$, does the following rank (rk) inequality hold
\begin{equation}
{\rm rk} (AB + BA) \le {\rm rk}(AB) + {\rm rk}(BA) \le {\rm min}({\rm rk} A, {\rm rk} B) + {\rm min}({\rm rk} B, {\rm rk} A) = 2 ~{\rm min}({\rm rk} A, {\rm rk} B) ?
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes, you just first apply the inequality $\text{rk}(A + B) \le \text{rk}(A) + \text{rk}(B)$ and then apply the inequality in the title.

Answer (score 1):

For Rob's extra question.
Try these:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
both of rank $1$.  Then
$$
AB = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
BA = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $AB+BA$ has rank $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the following two inequalities hold:

(1) The one in the title,

(2) ${\rm rk}(X+Y) \le {\rm rk}(X) + {\rm rk}(Y)$.

Apply the two inequalities and you can prove the one in your question.

Comment: Thanks, @Lapin. How about the maximum value of $rk (AB+BA)$ if both $rk A = rk B =1$? I mean I checked numerically with several examples and I dont find it greater than 1.

Comment: @Rob Can you get $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ and $B$ of rank $1$ so that $AB$ has a $1$ in the upper left but $BA$ has a $1$ in the lower right?

Comment: @GEdgar, doesn't seem so! You have any examples where $rk (AB+BA) > 1$ for $rk A = rk B = 1$?